# Diferencia entre AppCompatActivity y Activity

Tags: android

Tengo una pequeña duda que diferencia hay entre una AppCompatActivity y una Activity a la hora de extender una clase?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si usas librerías de soporte, estilo Material design pues debes usar `AppCompatActivity` las `Activity` está obsoleta, o bien si quieres realizar una app para un Android muy muy viejo.

Comment: He votado para reapertura. No entiendo por qué fue considerada como _demasiado amplia_.

Comment: @Webserveis no es al revés? AppCompatActivity sirve para usar material design en Androids viejos porque con Activity solo se podrá usar para Android 5.0 o superior.

Comment: @Xam aquí tienes más información Activity dejo de usarse des de hace mucho. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppCompatActivity: Es la super clase de un activity en la cual contiene metodos que heredaran o que pueden heredar de esa clase,

Activity: Es la vista que se le puede dar al usuario final, de la cual pueden implementar los metodos que existan dentro de AppCompatActivity
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/example-usage-of-appcompatactivity-in-android/)

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente la diferencia es que

### AppCompatActivity

Es la Clase base para las actividades que utilizan las funciones de la barra de acción (`ActionBar`) de la [biblioteca de soporte](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html).

Sabiendo que se puede agregar una `ActionBar` a nuestra actividad solamente cuando se ejecute en API de nivel 7 o superior extendiendo esta clase para su actividad y estableciendo el tema de actividad en `Theme.AppCompat` o un tema similar.

Ver: [Documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

Para que `AppCompatActivity` funcione se requieren los pasos siguientes:

1. Agregar dependencia en `build.gradle`

   ```
   android  { 
               compileSdkVersion 25  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
             }
   dependencies 
             {
               compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
             }
   ```
2. El `MainActivity` debe ser declarado así:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. El tema (Theme) de la Aplicación debe ser establecido del siguiente modo:

   `<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">`

---

### Activity

Una actividad es una cosa única y enfocada que el usuario puede hacer. Casi todas las actividades interactúan con el usuario, por lo que la clase `Activity` se encarga de crear una ventana en la que puede colocar su interfaz de usuario con `setContentView (View)`.

Si bien las actividades se presentan a menudo al usuario como ventanas de pantalla completa, también se pueden utilizar de otras formas: como ventanas flotantes (mediante un tema con el conjunto `windowIsFloating`) o incrustadas dentro de otra actividad (mediante `ActivityGroup`). Hay dos métodos que casi todas las subclases de `Activity` implementarán:

1. `OnCreate (Bundle)` es donde inicializa su actividad. Lo más importante es que aquí se suele llamar a `setContentView (int)` con un recurso de diseño que define la interfaz de usuario y usar `findViewById (int)` para recuperar los widgets de esa interfaz de usuario con los que necesita interactuar mediante programación.
2. `OnPause ()` es donde se trata de que el usuario abandone su actividad. Lo que es más importante, cualquier cambio realizado por el usuario debe ser comprometido en este momento (por lo general, el `ContentProvider` que contiene los datos).

Para ser útil con `Context.startActivity ()`, todas las clases de actividad deben tener una declaración correspondiente `<activity>` en el paquete `AndroidManifest.xml` de su paquete.

**Ciclo de vida de una Activity**

[image: Ciclo de Vida de una Activity - Documentación de Android]

Ver: [Documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)