# Android: Si finalizas una Activity tambien finalizan los procesos iniciados en esta?

Tags: android-studio, hilos, activity

Estoy diseñando una aplicación y me ha surgido ésta duda. Básicamente quiero saber si es posible ejecutar un Thread en una activity para que haga un proceso (en mi caso subir una imagen al servidor) y seguidamente cerrar la actividad (no me interesa que el usuario se tenga que esperar a que se suba la imagen para poder seguir usando la aplicación)

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Mira si [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/66933/29967) te puede servir, viendo el ciclo de vida de una  `Activity` en el gráfico (segunda parte de la respuesta).

Comment: podrias usar asyntask para subir en segundo plano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Thread que se inicia en segundo plano continuará corriendo independiente del Activity pero está sujeto a las reglas de Android en cuanto a que el proceso (linux) completo puede ser eliminado si se dan las condiciones necesarias.

Por ejemplo si el Activity que inició el Thread terminó porque el usuario navegó a otro Activity de la misma app, el Thread terminará de correr. En cambio si el Activity terminó porque el usuario fue a otra app o salio de la app e inició una nueva, Android podría reclamar la memoria y destruir el proceso que tienen el Thread todavía corriendo.